# Compiler fail - misconfiguration?

Tags: java, android

As it happened now for the second time I may have a misconfiguration somewhere.

```
private int calcTrackIndex(long pos){
    for(int i=0;i<=positions.length;i++){
        if(positions [i]>pos)return i-1; //one too far
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This function suddenly started to return -1, which, as the positions[] array starts with 0 cannot happen. After debugging for an half an hour I noticed that the debugger "skipped" the third line. I did "clean project"-"rebuild project" and everything was fine again.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent that? This error has been published to different emulators and devices using the "Run" and "Debug" buttons.

When this happens the debugger is not in sync with code anymore. This is not resolvable by restarting debug using the "debug" button, only clean-rebuild helps.

[image]
*The debugger is not in sync, it selects a line that does not exist in code.*

Comment: You returned `0-1` in the first iteration of the loop. It's a runtime bug, not a compilation problem

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [mcve] how this method is used. You seem to be missing how the `pos` variable is given to the method

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to debug your program. This is a critical skill for any computer programmer. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started.

Comment: no, it cannot return -1 as positions[0]=0 And why does "clean-project" "rebuild-project" resolve the problem? And why does the debugger skip lines? This is a debugger problem, not a code problem.

Comment: @cricket_007 a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example works exactly as it should and is not representative in this case. As Code-Apprentice already answered the class files may have not been updated correctly.

Comment: `positions[0]=0` has nothing to do with the return value. You're subtracting from `i` and never stated what `pos` is being assigned as. Therefore, code isn't complete. In any case, try disabling Instant Run if you're running into complier issues

Comment: pos is positive. Cannot be negative as it represents a track position. I cannot post the whole code, as the code leading to this position has more than 3k lines. As I have already stated this code works perfectly and without errors since I recompiled it. The bug occured because of a synchronizing problem between the class files. See the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After debugging for an half an hour I noticed that the debugger "skipped" the third line. I did "clean project"-"rebuild project" and everything was fine again.
>
> Why does this happen and how can I prevent that?

This occurs when the compiled .class files have not been rebuilt from the most recent version of your code. These compiled files contain line information from from the previous version of your code which the debugger is using.

As you saw, you can fix the problem by forcing your code to rebuild. This ensures that the compiled code matches the code you are editing in Android Studio.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this happen? As it only happens in my ubuntu environment it may be some misconfiguration of android studio.

Comment: Android Studio should detect changes to your code and rebuild your app, if necessary, every time you run it. Does this happen every time you make a change?

Comment: No, about every 50th compile, its a bit annoying as expecting code errors but the code isn't executed as it should